# How to make jetty-maven-plugin deploy a war that is retrieved from a repository?

Tags: maven-2, soapui, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm setting up an integration test module for a good sized web project. The integration test module is separated from the web project itself, and it has it's own pom.

The idea is to use the maven-soapui-plugin to send requests and verify the response. Setting up the soapui-plugin is no hassle. However, I'm having trouble with figuring out how I can tell the jetty-maven-plugin to deploy a war from a remote repository.

If I have understood correctly, the jetty-maven-plugin has a property called '<webApp>/<webApp>' which lets me specify the war file to deploy. The problem is that the war file is not present in the module itself.

I have heard that I can use the maven assembly plugin to retrieve the war from a repository via the projects artifactId, but I am yet to figure out how I would go about doing so.

Here's a summary of what I want:

1. Retrieve a specific war from a repository or the like, in example via its artifactId.
2. Deploy this war to the jetty-maven-plugin (goal deploy-war?)
3. get maven-soapui-plugin to run tests and report the results back in the integration-test phase.

I am pretty sure I've got step 3 covered, but I am very unsure how to achieve step 1 and 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **maybe** possible to use `dependency:copy` to retrieve the war, unpack it and to get the whole thing working with the maven jetty plugin, but this would be hacky and kinda ugly. A cleaner solution would be to use the [Maven Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) and this is my suggestion. Below, a sample POM showing how to retrieve a WAR artifact using its coordinates and how to deploy it on an embedded Jetty container using Cargo:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>war group id</groupId>
    <artifactId>war artifact id</artifactId>
    <type>war</type>
    <version>war version</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Container configuration -->
        <container>
          <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
          <type>embedded</type>
        </container>
        <!-- Configuration to use with the container or the deployer -->
        <configuration>
          <deployables>
            <deployable>
              <groupId>war group id</groupId>
              <artifactId>war artifact id</artifactId>
              <type>war</type>
              <properties>
                <context>war context</context>
              </properties>
            </deployable>
          </deployables>
        </configuration>
        <!-- Don't wait, execute the tests after the container is started -->
        <wait>false</wait>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>start-container</id>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>stop-container</id>
          <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

Finally, just bind the soapui plugin on the `integration-test` phase.

Comment: Hi Pascal. Thanks for the tip. This looks to be exactly what I am after. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: for parameter deployables: Cannot find 'deployables' in class org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.configuration.Configuration 

In my case for version 1.4.12 of cargo , the tag deployable is out of configuration.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18061722/1488761

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing the same thing, John, but I took a different approach with the Jetty plugin.  I think the end result is the same.  I'm developing an integration-test suite to run against several web service WARs.  I'm using `dependency:copy` in the `package` phase and then a list of `<contextHandler/>`s configured for `maven-jetty-plugin`:

```
<project>
    …
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-wars</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars-to-be-tested</outputDirectory>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            <artifactItems>
                                …
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                                    <version>version</version>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                                …
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
               </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.3.v20100526</version>
                <configuration>
                    …
                    <contextHandlers>
                        …
                        <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                            <war>${project.build.directory}/wars-to-be-tested/artifactId.war</war>
                            <contextPath>/context</contextPath>
                        </contextHandler>
                    </contextHandlers>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would prefer to declare the various wars as dependencies and then use `dependency:copy-dependencies` to set up the `wars-to-be-tested` directory; this would allow the Maven reactor to figure out that it needs to build my integration-test module after the wars it'll be testing.  The problem I ran into was that the Jetty plugin thought that I wanted to "overlay" all of the wars that were listed as dependencies (a concept that I'd never even heard of until I saw it happen); I don't know if allowing that to happen would have hurt anything, but I didn't like it, so I went with the `dependency:copy` method.

This is just an alternative to using Cargo.  I'll be looking into that myself, but I just wanted to provide another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@blaldor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678071/381083): add the `maven-dependency-plugin`, and then I had to modify it as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
  <configuration>
      <supportedPackagings>jar</supportedPackagings>
      <contextHandlers>
          <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
              <war>${project.build.directory}/wars-to-be-tested/artifactId.war</war>
          </contextHandler>
      </contextHandlers>
      <webApp>
          <contextPath>/artifactId</contextPath>
      </webApp>
```

(this was too big for a comment)