# Stopping jetty when changing Maven module?

Tags: maven-2, jetty, pom.xml

I've created a project that runs integration-tests on 3 web services. There's a project for each integration-test per web-service. I want all 3 integration-test projects to be run when executing the parent pom (outside of the 3 integration projects).

I've got the modules up and running but since each module deploys a WAR to its jetty instance, I have issues with port binding. The port is already in use since the first jetty instance isn't stopped before executing the next module.

My temporary solution is to bind to a different port for each of the projects by using the SelectChannelConnector, but a better solution would be that each jetty instance is shut down as soon as each module finishes. Is this possible?

Each module binds to the package (assembly), pre-integration-test (deploy war to jetty) and integration-test phase (runs SoapUI tests).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would merge all integration tests into a single module and use Cargo to start a container (jetty might be just fine) and deploy all required applications on it during pre-integration-test, run the soapui tests during integration-tests and stop the container during post-integration-test.

#### Related question

- [How to make jetty-maven-plugin deploy a war that is retrieved from a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677815/how-to-make-jetty-maven-plugin-deploy-a-war-that-is-retrieved-from-a-repository)

#### See also

- [Functional testing with Maven, Cargo and Selenium](http://www.jroller.com/carlossg/entry/functional_testing_with_maven_cargo)
- [Maven2 cargo plugin and integration test](http://codemeself.blogspot.com/2007/11/maven2-cargo-plugin-and-integration.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links and the suggestion :)